# Parse through XML in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

I am trying to parse through an XML and add every "Folder" to a ListView. As the number of folders changes through some XML files, I want the code to parse and get every folder. This is what part of the XML looks like:
[image: Screenshot of XML]

Now I want to read the folder section. This is the code I have so far:

```
If (document.Name = "countfolders") Then
 countfolder = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString
End If

x = 1
While (countfolder >= x)
 If (document.Name = "Folder" & x) Then
  ListBox1.Items.Add(document.ReadInnerXml.ToString)
  x += 1
 End If
End While
```

But it simply crashes. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is when it crashes? Also, do you have control over the format of the XML? Because if so, there are many better layouts you could use that would make this easier - e.g: `<Folders><Folder>ebay</Folder><Folder>GFX Urban Gardening</Folder></Folders` - this idea of repeated elements is common in XML. If you need to maintain order, you could use `<Folders><Folder id=1>ebay</Folder><Folder id=2>GFX</Folder></Folders>` - which would then maintain the order without changing the name of the element.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Thanks for the quick reply. By crashing I mean the app does not respond any more, but without any error information. Seems like it gets stuck somewhere.
Yes I do have control over making the XML. 
In one step I create the XML by reading the folders of a hard drive and put them into the XML like provided in the screenshot. In another step I want to read the folders into a ListView. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: Do you have an attached Visual Studio debugging? Perhaps try looking in the Output pane; you may see some information there. Also, is there any particular reason you aren't using LINQ? `For Each element In root.Elements.Where(Function(x) x,Name.StartsWith("Folder")): ListBox1.Items.Add(element.Value): Next`

Comment: It might help if you use [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). Something might be being converted to something else and making it go wrong - that setting will let you know about variable type mismatches. You should change the setting to make it the default for new projects too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem:

```
If (document.Name.Contains("Folder")) Then
 Dim test As String = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
 Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
 doc.LoadXml("<Folder>" & test & "</Folder>")
 Dim root As XmlNode = doc.FirstChild
 If root.HasChildNodes Then
  Dim _value = root.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
  ListBox1.Items.Add(_value)
 End If
End If
```

But thanks for your suggestions!